# UnicodeEncodeError: bulbs and neo4j create Model

Tags: python, unicode, neo4j, bulbs

I'm getting Unicode errors while trying to add data to Neo4J via Bulbs when the data contains non-ascii data.

the following code fails:

```
from bulbs.model import Node
from bulbs.property import String
from bulbs.neo4jserver import Graph

class User(Node):
    element_type="user"
    name = String(nullable=False)

g = Graph()
g.add_proxy("users", User)

user_data = {u'name': u'Aname M\xf6ller'}

g.users.create(**user_data)
```

with a `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf6' in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)`

The error is occurring in the `bulbs.utils.u` function, via `codecs.unicode_escape_decode()`.

Some hopefully relevant info:

```
$>python -V
'2.7.3'

>>>type(user_data['name'])
type('unicode')

>>>import bulbs
>>>bulbs.__version__
'0.3'
```

The Neo4J docs [state](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/graphdb-neo4j-properties.html) that all String objects are saved as unicode, so why is my unicode data not being accepted?  I hope I am just missing something silly.

Comment: `\xf6` is latin-1 for `ö` am I right?

Comment: @Paulo Bu.  correct an o with an umlaut.  Though I doubt it is the specific character that is causing the error.

Comment: What I'm suspect about is the `ascii` encoding, try this: `user_data = {u'name': u'Aname M\u00f6ller'}` It'll probably not work but just to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this was a bug. It's fixed in Bulbs 0.3.23:

https://github.com/espeed/bulbs/commit/7f104cdbc30f27ea76b036cfa0d0a694f074153e

Comment: @SunPowered: You should change your code and the accepted answer to to comply to this fix.

Comment: Fantastic! Open source in action

Answer (score 1):

After refreshing myself on Python and unicode, I got around the problem, though only by wrapping my problem line with a try, catch, and then encoding the problem data to 'utf-8'. Not the most elegant solution, but the following code seems to be working for me.

```
from bulbs.model import Node
from bulbs.property import String
from bulbs.neo4jserver import Graph

class User(Node):
    element_type="user"
    name = String(nullable=False)

g = Graph()
g.add_proxy("users", User)

user_data = {u'name': u'Aname M\xf6ller'}

try:
    g.users.create(**user_data)
except UnicodeEncodeError:
    for k, v in user_data.iteritems():
        try:
            user_data[k] = unicode.encode(v, 'utf-8')
        except TypeError:
            # Fails for non string values
            pass
    g.users.create(**user_data)
```

The only issue I have with this.   If the `bulbs` logger is active, then the error msg with a traceback are logged on the first call to  `create()`.  Not a deal breaker, just a bit annoying.

Haven't tried this on Python 3, any one have something to chime in on the matter?

Comment: I have the suspicion that `bulbs.utils`'s function `u` is handling encodings improperly. I filled an `issue` at their repo at github. Lets see. This is not a natural way to use the api for such a common feature (i18n).

Comment: I agree that this may be a bug in `bulbs` by using the aforementioned `codecs.unicode_escape_decode`, which as you point out in the Github Issue, is not documented at all in the python docs.  Thanks for the help @PauloBu

Comment: Yes, this was a bug. It's fixed in Bulbs 0.3.23 https://github.com/espeed/bulbs/commit/7f104cdbc30f27ea76b036cfa0d0a694f074153e Thanks.